# pytest: run test from code, not from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

Is it possible to run tests from code using pytest? I did find `pytest.main`, but it's just a command line interface available from code. I would like to pass a test class / function from the code.

In unittest it's possible this way:

```
from unittest import TestLoader, TestCase, TestResult


class TestMy(TestCase):
    def test_silly(self):
        assert False

runner = TestLoader()
test_suite = runner.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestMy)
test_result = TestResult()
test_suite.run(test_result)
print(test_result)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible, that way for instance:

```
from pytest import main


class TestMy:
    def test_silly(self):
        assert False


main(['{}::{}'.format(__file__, TestMy.__name__)])
```

You can pass any argument to `main` as if called from command line.